# Get active listitem in Bootstrap 4 unordered list using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap-4, css-selectors

```js
// Find the URL endpoint (similar to the database table name, usually)
var endpoint = document
  .querySelector(".dropdown-menu > .active > a")
  .getAttribute("href")
  .split(".")[1]
  .replace("/", "");
console.log("endpoint: " + endpoint);
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-xs navbar-dark bg-dark mb-2" role="navigation">
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#admin-navbar-collapse" aria-controls="admin-navbar-collapse" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="admin-navbar-collapse">
      <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
        <li class="active dropdown show">
          <ul class="dropdown-menu show">
            <li>
              <a class="dropdown-item active" href="/admin/admin.gateways/">
            Gateways</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="/admin/admin.sim_cards/">
            SIM Cards</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>

  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

**JavaScript Rookie Alert!**

How do I select the *active* `dropdown-item` in the dropdown menu, so I know in JavaScript which page I'm on?

I tried `document.querySelector(".dropdown-menu > .active > a")` for the following HTML navbar, but it returned `null`. In Bootstrap 3, this worked fine, but not in Bootstrap 4.

Once I can select the right `dropdown-item`, I'll grab its `href` with `.getAttribute("href")`

```html
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="admin-navbar-collapse">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="/" style="padding-top: 10px; padding-bottom: 10px;">
    <img src="/static/img/logo.png" height="34px" width="auto">
  </a>
  <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
    <li class="active dropdown show">
      <ul class="dropdown-menu show">
        <li>
          <a class="dropdown-item active" href="/admin/admin.gateways/">
            Gateways</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="/admin/admin.sim_cards/">
            SIM Cards</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: The `a` element you're after isn't the child of an `.active` element it holds the class itself. `document.querySelector(".dropdown-menu a.active").href`

Comment: If the HTML and the CSS were written correctly in first place, the effort in JS was much less too. Thus one needs to fix the HTML/CSS first ... one wants to have a somehow active/selected list item ... then one also has to express/write it like that ... `<li class="selected">` ... accompanied by the right css selectors like e.g. `li a { ... }`, `li.selected { ... }`, `li.selected a { ... }` ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@pilchard nailed it with his comment:

```js
document.querySelector(".dropdown-menu a.active").href
```

```js
// Find the URL endpoint (similar to the database table name, usually)
var endpoint = document
  .querySelector(".dropdown-menu a.active").href
console.log("endpoint: " + endpoint);
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-xs navbar-dark bg-dark mb-2" role="navigation">
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#admin-navbar-collapse" aria-controls="admin-navbar-collapse" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="admin-navbar-collapse">
      <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
        <li class="active dropdown show">
          <ul class="dropdown-menu show">
            <li>
              <a class="dropdown-item active" href="/admin/admin.gateways/">
            Gateways</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="/admin/admin.sim_cards/">
            SIM Cards</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>

  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```